# How does a binary delta update work?

Tags: software-updates, software-patches, diff

Both Android and iOS seem to support their application having a binary delta update. But how does it work? I build a binary program, neither of the distribution sites have the source code - how does the update process know what is changed?

Comment: Look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1945075/how-do-i-create-binary-patches and http://www.daemonology.net/bsdiff/

Answer (score 9):

Just as you can create a patch for a text (source) file, you can create a patch for a binary file as well.

You are effectively just noting what changed between two files (that's called [delta encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_encoding)).

For example, if the app contains many resources, then those don't usually change for smaller updates, and only the executable code itself needs to be transferred.